# DJava.library.path doesn't work, but adding directory to PATH works

Tags: java, path

I have a JAR file that needs some external DLL to work. I load those DLL with

```
System.loadLibrary("openalprjni");
```

If I try to execute the JAR without any parameters, the DLL won't be found (obviously) :

```
> java -jar dist\ALPRTest.jar "param1" "param2"
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no openalprjni in java.library.path
```

If I try to add the path to DLLs with Djava.library.path, it doesn't work either (*note that I append my new path to the existing path instead of overriding it*)

```
> java -Djava.library.path="%PATH%;D:\ALPRTest\path-to-dll" -jar dist\ALPRTest.jar "param1" "param2"
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\ALPRTest\dist\openalprjni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Notice that now the error is `Can't find dependent libraries` instead of a plain `no xxx in java.library.path`. I don't know what that means however.

The only way the program will run is if I add manually `D:\ALPRTest\path-to-dll` to my PATH variable in the Windows control panel.

If I use `-XshowSettings:properties`, I can confirm that both `java.library.path` are absolutely identical, but the JAR won't run unless I add this path manually to the PATH.

**Why is `-Djava.library.path` not working, but adding to PATH working ?**

Comment: You are not appending to the existing *library* path, you are appending to the contents of the `PATH` environment variable. Can you post the actual paths you are using? Are you using the full path including the name of the DLL or just its directory? Can you print the value of `java.library.path` from inside the program?

Comment: When loading the library in Java, I only use its name, no path (like I showed in the first block). If I print the content of `java.library.path` in the main method, I can see the absolute path to my DLLs is there, but I still have an UnsatisfiedLinkError, even if the DLLs are in the proper path.

Comment: It works even if I remove the `DJava.library.path` option, when the absolute path to the DLLs are in the PATH variable

Comment: The problem may be that even with java.library.path set correctly, Windows will not look in anything other than its PATH for dependent libraries. Refer to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213772?focusedCommentId=14222348&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14222348 and https://rgrzywinski.wordpress.com/2006/03/27/cant-find-dependent-libraries/

Comment: @zhenguoli How is this not documented and more well-known?!? I just spent 12 hours and this ended up being the issue. Thank you for your comment...